# Angular data-table horizontal scrollbar

Tags: angularjs, datatables

I am using Angular data table and I want to apply horizontal scrollbar. Previously I used jQuery data-tables, its quite easy in jQuery but I didn't find same for Angular data-tables.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please take a time to go through [the welcome tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to know your way around here (and also to earn your first badge), read how to [create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and also check [How to Ask Good Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so you increase your chances to get feedback and useful answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its quite easy with Angular data-tables.
Simply add 'dtOptions' to your table.
and configure same as follows
$scope.dtOptions = DTOptionsBuilder.newOptions().withOption('scrollX', '100%');

Answer (score 0):

Use the following configurations in your typescript and html template file respectively

```js
dtOptions: any = {};
ngOnInit() {
      this.dtOptions = {
      // other configurations
      scrollX: true,
}
```

```html
<table datatable [dtOptions]="dtOptions"></table>
```